lme4 (glmer): Something buggy with treatment of factors in 4-way interactions
I have a dataset for which I am making a series of complex generalized linear mixed-effects models with the lme4 package in R.  I have experience with glmer and this type of experimental data, but I've come across something odd in the structure of the "factored" effects in my models specifically when the model includes a 4-way interaction.
Note that this issue only crops up when I introduce 4-way interactions. I am hoping that someone can confirm for me whether this is a bug or "feature" of lme4, or rather a logical error on my part.
Description of my dataset:
The predicted variable in my dataset is a binomial called "Response.numeric"
I have the following four effects of interest in this dataset:

"VOT_scaled" (centered/scaled numbers relating to a quality of the stimuli; this goes on the x-axis, for context see the plot below)
"POA" (a factor with three levels: "bilabial", "alveolar", and "velar"; this is the troublesome variable!)
"English_Experience_Composite" (centered/scaled numbers capturing an individual difference in participants)
"Trial_order_scaled" (centered/scaled numbers capturing time across the task)

If it helps you to visualize the output of this, here is a plot of the super-duper complex interactions among these four effects of interest:

This is how the maximal model is coded:
glmer(Response.numeric ~ 1 + VOT_scaled + POA + English_Experience_Composite + Trial_order_scaled +
                                     VOT_scaled:POA + VOT_scaled:English_Experience_Composite + VOT_scaled:Trial_order_scaled +
                                     POA:English_Experience_Composite + POA:Trial_order_scaled +
                                     English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled +
                                     VOT_scaled:POA:English_Experience_Composite +
                                     VOT_scaled:POA:Trial_order_scaled +
                                     VOT_scaled:POA:English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled +
                                     (1 + VOT_scaled + POA + Trial_order_scaled | Subject) + (1 | Audio),
                                   data = all_pretest_data, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                                   control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e9)))

This is the model summary output from that monster-of-a-model. Focus on the names of the estimates toward the bottom. This is where things get weird. Note that "bilabial" is the reference level of "POA" (contrasted against "alveolar" and "velar"). The model below uses dummy-coding, but I have also tried this with contrast coding and the same thing happens.
Up through the 3-way interactions, I get summary output showing estimates of "alveolar" and "velar" (against the reference "bilabial"). But four the 4-way interaction, it changes to showing me estimates of "bilabial", "alveolar", and "velar". It's as though it decides for the four-way interaction that "bilabial" is no longer the reference level -- and I have no clue why.
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: Response.numeric ~ 1 + VOT_scaled + POA + English_Experience_Composite +  
    Trial_order_scaled + VOT_scaled:POA + VOT_scaled:English_Experience_Composite +  
    VOT_scaled:Trial_order_scaled + POA:English_Experience_Composite +  
    POA:Trial_order_scaled + English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled +  
    VOT_scaled:POA:English_Experience_Composite + VOT_scaled:POA:Trial_order_scaled +  
    VOT_scaled:POA:English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled +  
    (1 + VOT_scaled + POA + Trial_order_scaled | Subject) + (1 |      Audio)
   Data: all_pretest_data
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+09))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 17576.6  17895.6  -8750.3  17500.6    32667 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-21.6972  -0.1465   0.0979   0.2464  12.1234 

Random effects:
 Groups  Name               Variance Std.Dev. Corr                   
 Subject (Intercept)        2.20241  1.4841                          
         VOT_scaled         0.82481  0.9082    0.28                  
         POAalveolar        1.32088  1.1493   -0.73 -0.07            
         POAvelar           1.58353  1.2584   -0.79 -0.10  0.85      
         Trial_order_scaled 0.09583  0.3096    0.19 -0.11 -0.16 -0.38
 Audio   (Intercept)        0.46703  0.6834                          
Number of obs: 32705, groups:  Subject, 248; Audio, 24

Fixed effects:
                                                                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                                                             2.57287    0.26740   9.622  < 2e-16 ***
VOT_scaled                                                              2.12924    0.25737   8.273  < 2e-16 ***
POAalveolar                                                            -0.48968    0.35874  -1.365 0.172257    
POAvelar                                                               -0.57080    0.36091  -1.582 0.113744    
English_Experience_Composite                                           -0.07062    0.11746  -0.601 0.547668    
Trial_order_scaled                                                     -0.01610    0.05202  -0.310 0.756933    
VOT_scaled:POAalveolar                                                  1.18336    0.35382   3.344 0.000824 ***
VOT_scaled:POAvelar                                                     0.84765    0.35339   2.399 0.016456 *  
VOT_scaled:English_Experience_Composite                                 0.29023    0.08701   3.336 0.000851 ***
VOT_scaled:Trial_order_scaled                                           0.06275    0.04641   1.352 0.176301    
POAalveolar:English_Experience_Composite                               -0.14160    0.10946  -1.294 0.195789    
POAvelar:English_Experience_Composite                                  -0.11791    0.11728  -1.005 0.314735    
POAalveolar:Trial_order_scaled                                         -0.17228    0.06981  -2.468 0.013590 *  
POAvelar:Trial_order_scaled                                            -0.11052    0.06654  -1.661 0.096754 .  
English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled                        -0.04743    0.03730  -1.272 0.203477    
VOT_scaled:POAalveolar:English_Experience_Composite                    -0.25439    0.08493  -2.995 0.002741 ** 
VOT_scaled:POAvelar:English_Experience_Composite                       -0.27278    0.08550  -3.191 0.001420 ** 
VOT_scaled:POAalveolar:Trial_order_scaled                              -0.15998    0.07729  -2.070 0.038462 *  
VOT_scaled:POAvelar:Trial_order_scaled                                 -0.13220    0.06965  -1.898 0.057705 .  
VOT_scaled:POAbilabial:English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled -0.12985    0.04622  -2.810 0.004959 ** 
VOT_scaled:POAalveolar:English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled -0.06288    0.05687  -1.106 0.268871    
VOT_scaled:POAvelar:English_Experience_Composite:Trial_order_scaled    -0.06085    0.04836  -1.258 0.208248    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Some additional notes:

levels(all_pretest_data$POA) gives me: "bilabial" "alveolar" "velar"

contrasts(all_pretest_data$POA) gives me:
            alveolar velar

bilabial         0     0
alveolar        1     0
velar             0     1

I have tried remaking the model with contrast coding and the same thing happens:

i.e., I've tried: contrasts(all_pretest_data$POA) <- cbind(c(-.5, .5, 0), c(-.5, 0, .5))


I have some other very similar datasets for this paper, and the same thing happens anytime I introduce four-way interactions (hence my suspicion this is either a bug or "feature" I don't know about...)


Data and model (RDS file) are on Google Drive at: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lG7M44kGQxRQiOK8WIMk5qI9zmTDmpbJ?usp=sharing

If you want to look at it I will also upload my R code but you should only really look at Lines:

210 (read in data)

267-276 (model code -- same as above)

283 (code to read in RDS file so you don't have to converge the model yourself)





SOLUTION: The model was missing a 3-way interaction.

Yup. See my answer. If you specify your model as Response~VOT*POA*EEC*TOS you can save a lot of trouble ...

Could you please either write up your own answer to this question, or, if my answer is good enough, click the check-mark to accept it? It's nice to close the loop/show that the question has been answered.

This is happening because you (intentionally or unintentionally) excluded two of the possible three-way interactions from your formula. In order to specify all of the terms of the four-way interactions, R has to include the 'weird' terms.
I've stripped down the example and abbreviated the variable names for clarity.
dummy data set
For the purposes of this example we only need the variables to have the right type/factor levels.
dd <- data.frame(VOT = 1.0,
                 POA = factor(c("bi", "al", "ve"),
                              levels = c("bi", "al", "ve")),
                 EEC = 1.0,
                 TOS = 1.0)

original formula
I constructed this by replacing the terms in your formula with their abbreviations. Note that only two of the four possible three-way interaction terms are included.
form1 <- ~ 1 +
    VOT + POA + EEC + TOS +
    VOT:POA + VOT:EEC + VOT:TOS + POA:EEC + POA:TOS +  EEC:TOS +
    VOT:POA:EEC + VOT:POA:TOS +
    VOT:POA:EEC:TOS

Checking the names of the coefficients/terms in the model:
(nm1 <- colnames(model.matrix(form1, dd)))
 [1] "(Intercept)"       "VOT"               "POAal"            
 [4] "POAve"             "EEC"               "TOS"              
 [7] "VOT:POAal"         "VOT:POAve"         "VOT:EEC"          
[10] "VOT:TOS"           "POAal:EEC"         "POAve:EEC"        
[13] "POAal:TOS"         "POAve:TOS"         "EEC:TOS"          
[16] "VOT:POAal:EEC"     "VOT:POAve:EEC"     "VOT:POAal:TOS"    
[19] "VOT:POAve:TOS"     "VOT:POAbi:EEC:TOS" "VOT:POAal:EEC:TOS"
[22] "VOT:POAve:EEC:TOS"

grep("bi", nm1, value = TRUE)
[1] "VOT:POAbi:EEC:TOS"

There are occasionally good theoretical reasons to leave out some of the lower-order interactions, but (1) you have to think carefully about whether these really make sense and (2) it's hard to specify this with R's formula interface (if you really need to I can show how to do it).
add missing three-way interactions
form2 <- update(form1, ~ . + VOT:EEC:TOS + POA:EEC:TOS)

(nm2 <- colnames(model.matrix(form2, dd)))
 [1] "(Intercept)"       "VOT"               "POAal"            
 [4] "POAve"             "EEC"               "TOS"              
 [7] "VOT:POAal"         "VOT:POAve"         "VOT:EEC"          
[10] "VOT:TOS"           "POAal:EEC"         "POAve:EEC"        
[13] "POAal:TOS"         "POAve:TOS"         "EEC:TOS"          
[16] "VOT:POAal:EEC"     "VOT:POAve:EEC"     "VOT:POAal:TOS"    
[19] "VOT:POAve:TOS"     "VOT:EEC:TOS"       "POAal:EEC:TOS"    
[22] "POAve:EEC:TOS"     "VOT:POAal:EEC:TOS" "VOT:POAve:EEC:TOS"

grep("bi", nm2, value = TRUE)
character(0)

If you do want the model with all possible interactions up to and including the four-way interactions, it's much easier to specify it this way: it gives the same coefficients (albeit in a slightly different order) as the hand-specified formula.
form3 <- ~VOT*POA*EEC*TOS
nm3 <- colnames(model.matrix(form3, dd))
all.equal(sort(nm2), sort(nm3))

